# How can I say "Staff Only" with a formal warning sentence?

Tags: formality, idiom-requests

I need to write a door writing that states formally, "students are not welcomed in this kitchen, please use the café..."

I've drafted some examples but I was wondering if there is a formal sentence which may sound more formal (like a warning from the principal) and also more native.

z.B. "staff only"

"Students are not allowed"

"We kindly request students to use the ... Cafe provided." or What about 
""We kindly request students to use the other areas(opportunities) provided for the tea service."

Comment: When you state "Kitchen" do you literally mean a Kitchen as in a cooking area?  Or do you mean more like a cafeteria or seating area?  If the former, a typical sign would be something along the lines of "Restricted area: Only staff are allowed beyond this point." or if you want to be more precise:  "Restricted area: Kitchen staff only" or "Restricted area: Employees only"

Comment: It is not a cooking area, just hot drinks, grab and go. But only for instructors, not for students actually.

Comment: What's wrong with "Staff Only"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be authoritative. But do you also want to be nice about it, or do you want to be intimidating and scary? Here are several options, from nice to threatening and scary.

Nice: "Staff only please."

Still kind of nice: "Staff only. Students please use the cafe."

Firm: "Staff only. All others keep out."

Harsh: "Staff only. Unauthorized access prohibited."

Threatening: "Only school staff allowed. Trespassers will be PROSECUTED."

Menacingly Sarcastic: "BEWARE: Killer dogs will attack unauthorized persons. Staff only."

Answer (score 1):

Staff only is short and to the point.  "Students not allowed" is very specific and we can infer that teachers, parents, visitors etc are allowed.